# Distribution of covariance parameter resulting from sum of known- and unknown-covariance noise processes

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

Let's say I have a set $X$ of $N$ random $p$-dimensional vectors generated by $\mathbf{x}_i = \boldsymbol{\mu} + \Psi_i^{1/2} \boldsymbol{\xi}_i + \Sigma^{1/2} \boldsymbol{\zeta}_i$, where $\boldsymbol{\xi}_i, \; \boldsymbol{\zeta}_i \sim \mathcal{N}_p(\mathbf{0}, \mathbb{I})$ are $p$-variate standard normally distributed noise processes, and $\Psi_i$ and $\Sigma$ are $p \times p$ covariance matrices. Note which terms have subscripts: each vector has its own $\Psi_i$, but they all share the same $\Sigma$; and the noise generated by *either* process is different for each vector.

If we know all the $\Psi_i$'s, but $\Sigma$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ are unknown, is there a way to find $\Sigma | X,$ the density of the true value of $\Sigma$ given the observed data?

As a jumping off point, in the simpler case where there is just one unknown noise process and $\mathbf{x}_i = \Sigma^{1/2} \boldsymbol\zeta_i$, we have that $\Sigma|X \sim \text{inv-Wish}_{p,N-1}(S^{-1})$, where $S = \sum_{i=1}^N (\mathbf{x}_i - \hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}})(\mathbf{x}_i - \hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}})^T$, in which $\hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N \mathbf{x}_i $ is the MLE for the mean, leading ultimately to a multivariate $t$-distribution for the error in the mean $\hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}} - \boldsymbol\mu$.

For large $N$ it is very likely OK to simply subtract the mean from the original expression, square both sides, take the expectation value, and sum over observations to obtain

$\langle S\rangle = \sum_i\Psi_i + N \Sigma$

and therefore

$\Sigma = \frac{1}{N}\left(\langle S\rangle - \sum_i \Psi\right)$,

but this method of course runs into trouble for low $N$, where it is quite likely, especially if $\Sigma$ is small, that we could have sampled vectors that have less sample variance than suggested even by the $\Psi$'s alone and thereby wind up with a non-positive definite answer for $\Sigma$.

My intuition is that in such a scenario, all we really should know is that $\Sigma$ is likely to be smaller than $\frac{1}{N} \sum_i \Psi_i$, and perhaps implement an uninformed prior below that. But I'd really like to have a result that is rigorous in this limit, and also correctly interpolates the different scenarios. Is there any accepted way to disentangle the distribution for this unknown variance from data subject to both it and additional noise processes with known variances?

I should add that I'm aware that exactly what answer is obtained may depend on the choice of uninformed prior; the inverse Wishart distribution I mentioned above comes from using the Jeffreys prior density $\Sigma \sim |\Sigma|^{-(p+1)/2}$, but I'm open to other suggestions for reasonable priors appropriate for this problem.